# Append dot and counter as suffix for values encountered more than once like R's make.unique function

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I need the same functionality of R function [make.unique](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/make.unique) in PHP.

In R:

```
> dup_array = c("a", "b", "a", "c")
> make.unique(dup_array)
[1] "a"   "b"   "a.1" "c"
```

In PHP:

```
> dup_array = array("a", "b", "a", "c")
> magic_function(dup_array)
```

What is the `magic_function`?

Comment: well i understand it may not be the same but close, does this help? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php. Or you can also create your own magic function using `array_count_values` in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are no in-built functions already for this *as yet*, however, you can create your own custom function for it.

Keep track of current frequency of the element using a dictionary(associative array) and then attach the current frequency accordingly.

```
<?php

function makeUnique($arr){
    $set = [];
    foreach($arr as $k => $v){
        $set[ $v ] = ($set[ $v ] ?? 0) + 1;
        $arr[ $k ] = $arr[ $k ] . ($set[ $v ] > 1 ? '.' .($set[ $v ] - 1) : '');
    }
    return $arr;
}

print_r(makeUnique($arr));
```

[**Online Demo**](https://3v4l.org/Rh6RJ)

Comment: @Sanxofon Yes, using a simple dictionary or set makes it more compact and straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
<?php
function make_unique($a) {
    $d = array_count_values($a);
    $f = array_filter($d, function($k){
        return $k>1;
    });
    $k = array_keys($f);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($a); $i++) { 
        if(in_array($a[$i],$k) && $d[$a[$i]]>0) {
            $f[$a[$i]]--;
            $n = $d[$a[$i]]-$f[$a[$i]];
            if($n>1)$a[$i] = $a[$i].".".($n-1);
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
```

You can test it:

```
$a = ["a","d","c","b","a","b","a","a","d","d","a"];
print_r(make_unique($a));
```

And results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => d
    [2] => c
    [3] => b
    [4] => a.1
    [5] => b.1
    [6] => a.2
    [7] => a.3
    [8] => d.1
    [9] => d.2
    [10] => a.4
)
```

Comment: This unexplained answer is doing a lot of cycles.

Answer (score 0):

- Maintain a lookup array by incrementing the counter relating to each encountered value as you iterate.
- Only present the dot and the lookup's value if it is not `0`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/565rt))

```
$array = ["a", "b", "a", "c"];

var_export(
    array_map(
        function ($v) {
            static $lookup = [];
            return sprintf(
                '%s%s%s' ,
                $v,                             // show original value
                ($lookup[$v] ??= 0) ? '.' : '', // declare lookup element, show dot if not zero
                $lookup[$v]++ ?: ''             // show counter if not zero, then increment
            );
        },
        $array
    )
);
```

The compact version:

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function ($v) {
            static $lookup = [];
            return $v . (($lookup[$v] ??= 0) ? '.' : '') . ($lookup[$v]++ ?: '');
        },
        $array
    )
);
```

Bear in mind that using a lookup array is only safe IF all of the values in your array are scalar and will not be mutated by PHP upon being used as a key.  For instance, if you try to use `null`, a boolean value, a float, an array, or an object, etc. -- then a lookup is not suitable.  Errm, well, if you have an unstable or unsuitable value, you could translate it to a unique string before using it as a lookup key.